Azure app registration Client secret expired- CORS error on API
I have ASP.net backend with NextJS frontend application.
I am using Azure AD for authentication.
Since yesterday I am getting CORS error on my API. I checked and found that a "client secret" expired in Azure app registration. I have create a new one but I have no idea where do I need to update this?
"Allow public client flow" under authentication is set to "No"
I checked all config files and the entire token flow, I could only see the application id an tenant id being used on both sides of the application.
I have not made any changes to this application and do not see any other issue except this expired client secret.

AFAIK, CORS error throws due different domain name is trying to access different domain which is not allowed request due to CORS policy.
If You are getting CORS error cross check you have enabled CORS in your ASP.Net application.
To Enable CORS in Azure portal in App Service you need to go to your ASP.Net application -> API -> CORS

Add your frontend domain name in allowed origin.
or you can add * for any origin.


As Far As Client secret is concerned
You need update client secrete in your ASP.Net  appsettings.json file's Azure ADsection  for ASP application.
If client secret of your NEXTJS Front end is expired you can make changes in your code where you have used MSAL authentication.
